# Can you use facts in a YAML based Bolt plan?

Tags: yaml, puppet, bolt

The Bolt docs on [Writing plans in YAML](https://puppet.com/docs/bolt/latest/writing_yaml_plans.html) gives an code snippet that is not supposed to work:

```
steps:
  - targets: $targets
    description: Apply a file resource
    resources:
    - type: file
      title: '/tmp/foo'
      parameters:
        content: $facts['os']['family']
        ensure: present
  - name: file_contents
    description: Read contents of file managed with file resource
    eval: >
      file::read('/tmp/foo')
      
return: $file_contents
```

This snippet could be vastly improved with a GIANT RED "THIS DOES NOT WORK" right next to it.

I want to do exactly that: use a values from `facts` in a step.  I understand I could use the puppet language to do so, but I'd like to use YAML.

EDIT: How can you write the above in YAML?

Comment: Yeah, this is poor docs practice. I'll put a PR up to change it. Sorry for the confusion. If you don't get the help you need here, someone might be able to help you with your question over in the 
[Puppet community Slack](puppetcommunity.slack.com). Channel: #bolt.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `facts` [function](https://puppet.com/docs/bolt/latest/plan_functions.html#facts) instead to be safe, and functions [are possible in YAML plans](https://puppet.com/docs/bolt/latest/writing_yaml_plans.html#calling-functions).

```
${facts(<target>)['os']['family']}
```

Since the step in the question already supplies a `target` type, it does not need to be converted from a `TargetSpec` type with `get_target` like in Puppet language plans.

Note that you may need to gather the facts with another plan before referencing them:

```
steps:
- plan: facts
  description: 'Gather facts for the servers using the built-in facts plan'
  parameters:
    targets:
    - foo.example.com
    - bar.example.com
    - baz.example.com
```

Comment: What would be the value of <target> to get the current target this is being run on.  Let's say I want that step to get the ${facts(<target>)['os']['family']} for foo.example.com without hardcoding it.  I've tried "$target" and "$host" and both come back with "Evaluation Error: Unknown variable: ..."

Comment: Have you tried using TargetSpec to pass in the current target? Example here: https://puppet.com/docs/bolt/latest/writing_yaml_plans.html#using-variables-and-simple-expressions

Comment: I don't get how to go from $targets which is a list of hosts to run on to $target which can be used as a argument to `${facts(<target>)['os']['family']}`

Comment: I have modified the question.  Thanks for your help so far.